# Routing with if condition in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, if-statement, routes, vuetify.js

This is my code within in router.js file

```
 {
      name: "Admin",
      path: "/admin/",
      component: () => import("@/views/admin/Index"),
      children: [
      
        // Dashboard
        {
          name: "Dashboard",
          path:   "dash",
          component: () => import("@/views/admin/Dash"),
        },
        {
          name: "Campaign Management",
          path: "campaign",
          component: () =>
          import("@/views/CampaignManagementNew/CampaignManagment"),
        },
   ]
}
```

I set a variable 'status' in the localStorage.

I want to route only, if 'status' is true (localStorage item).
Otherwise, I not need to routing to child components.

How I use if conditions to routing?

Comment: What you need is a navigational gaurd. Check more about it here https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-resolve-guards

Answer (score 0):

You want to implement a pretty common pattern for 'protecting' routes behind a flag. In order to accomplish this, you should add a `meta` property to the routes you want to 'protect' behind a secondary check (the localStore value). Then you will need to create a router guard that checks the meta flag and routes the user based on those conditions.

You can see an example of it here: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/meta.html#route-meta-fields

In your case you would want to replace the `auth.loggedIn()` with your function that can check the localStorage value. So something like this:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresLocalStorageValue)) {
    if (!checkLocalStorageValue()) {
      next({ path: '/not-authorized-page-missing-local-store'})
    } else {
      next()
    }
  } else {
    next() // make sure to always call next()!
  }
})
```